# Find max among 32 bit integers

Tags: assembly, sse

Is there instruction in `SSE/SSE2` able to find max/min in 4 integers 32-bit?
I tried search something but I found only instructions for 16/8 bit.
Thanks in advance.

https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=max&expand=4465,4463,3278&techs=SSE,SSE2

Comment: Are you looking for a horizontal operation?  Or 4 packed max operations in parallel, like `pmaxsd`?  If you need a horizontal max with SSE2, just store to memory and use scalar.  With SSE4.1, then maybe shuffling like for a horizontal sum would be fastest.  Horizontal operations are slow.  If your algorithm needs a lot of them, you're using SIMD wrong.  See the [SSE tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/sse/info) for guides.

Comment: "Are you looking for a horizontal operation? " I am looking for operations in parallel. Ok, you suggest to store to memory and use scalar operations. ( in case of horizontal). But why do you suggest doing it? After all, there is no advantage from usage of SIMD. Do you mean, that horizontal operation are as fast as "store to memory and compare in "normal" ( scalar) way?

Comment: If you have exactly 4 numbers, rather than 1000 numbers, there's not much benefit from SIMD.  (Unless your numbers are unsigned 16bit, so you can use the special-purpose [`PHMINPOSUW`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/PHMINPOSUW.html)).  Horizontal means "within a single vector", as opposed to what SIMD is good at (e.g. add a[0] to b[0], a[1] to b[1], etc.).  If you need to find a horizontal max of 4 elements, without SSE4.1, then you probably can't beat scalar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way without SSE4.1 seems to be a 32bit compare, and then use that mask to blend: `AND(mask, x) OR ANDN(mask, y)`.

[Agner Fog's vector class library](http://www.agner.org/optimize/#vectorclass) has [a function for it](https://github.com/pcordes/vectorclass/blob/master/vectori128.h#L2212):

```
// function max: a > b ? a : b
static inline Vec4i max(Vec4i const & a, Vec4i const & b) {
#if INSTRSET >= 5   // SSE4.1 supported
    return _mm_max_epi32(a,b);
#else
    __m128i greater = _mm_cmpgt_epi32(a,b);
    return selectb(greater,a,b);
#endif
}
```

I have some mostly-untested and not-yet-merged changes for that library [on github](https://github.com/pcordes/vectorclass).  Most of my changes are significant improvements to the few functions I've had time to look at (integer horizontal sums, quadword arithmetic right shift, quadword multiply).  (Testing / feedback welcome!)

But a lot of the existing code is quite good, so I'd definitely recommend using those wrapper classes.  They don't add overhead when you build with optimizations enabled, and they make the syntax a hell of a lot easier.  e.g. `a+b` instead of `_mm_add_epi32(a,b)`.

Comment: Maybe horizontal operations are low lying fruit. I mean they are not operations you would normally want in a critical loop so optimizing them is not so important. Have you found any critical functions in the VCL that need optimizationg? The most difficult part of the VCL I think is permutes and blends. See for example [this](http://agner.org/optimize/vectorclass/read.php?i=120). I htink this is the most difficult area to implement with a general class.

Comment: @Zboson: yeah, it turns out it all of VCL always uses `vpblendvb` (2 uops and needs a mask from memory), even for compile-time-constant blends.  Next on my list is to fix the templates to use the much faster `vpblendd` or `pblendw`, when possible.  I also pushed a speedup for `operator >> (Vec2q)` (emulating the missing `psarq`), where I did significantly better for the 128b version than just changing variable-blend to immediate-blend.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34122605/how-to-optimize-simd-transpose-function-8x4-4x8/34207876#34207876) is another interesting example. I got it right eventually but the problem is that I had to try several variations before the VCL produced ideal code instead of bad code.

Comment: @Zboson: So there are patterns that should have turned into a simple shuffle, but didn't?  I haven't looked to see if it recognizes every possible shuffle pattern.  There are already a lot of special case patterns!  Oh, I see the OP's code maybe sucked, so that could be a test-case.  However, keep in mind there's no hope for the VCL to optimize between separate statements.  So you will still have to know what shuffles the hardware has available, even if the VCL metaprogramming for `blend8f<...>` is perfect.  A single `blend8fx8` to optimize 8-input 8-output shuffles would be insane...

Answer (score 2):

Maybe [`PMAXSD`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/PMAXSD.html) does the trick?

> Compares packed signed dword integers in the destination operand (first operand) and the source operand (second operand), and returns the maximum for each packed value in the destination operand.

However, it requires SSE 4.1 and/or AVX support.